# ArrayList.add not functioning in method

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am currently developing an android project using eclipse JAVA and I had just written the method below,

```
ArrayList<string> question, modelAnswer, correctAnswer, answer1, answer2, answer3, picture, questionNo;

public void QuestionGenerator(String[][] array, int number ){
    if (number > array.length){
        number = array.length;
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));
    for (int i=0; i<number; i++){
        question.add(array[i][0]);
        modelAnswer.add(array[i][1]);
        answer1.add(array[i][1]);
        answer2.add(array[i][2]);
        answer3.add(array[i][3]);
        picture.add(array[i][4]);
        questionNo.add(array[i][5]);
    }
}
```

But I am having the error of "The method add(R.string) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String)" coming up for the add function for those array lists. Could anyone suggest me why I got this? Is the method can't handle with 2d array or why?

Thanks

Comment: ArrayList<string> must be ArrayList<String>?

Comment: @narek.gevorgyan Yes, I got it solved by fixing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the uppercase String :)

```
ArrayList<String> question, modelAnswer, correctAnswer, answer1, answer2, answer3, picture, questionNo;
```

And initialize the ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();
(...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The question is successfully solved by your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have to call `add(getString(R.string.YOUR_STRING_NAME))`

Answer (score 0):

According to ArrayList declaration its accepting only String data.

But If try to add R.string.yourid which is integer identifier for string resource.

So you need to getString(R.string.yourid) then add that to your Arraylist

```
question.add(getString(R.string.yourid));
```

also since you are adding String object make `ArrayList<String> question;`